# Vagrant for virtual linux dev - how to know if the vm startup is "hanging" ? 

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant

Hi guys : I have recently installed vagrant, and am learning about it.  I notice it takes a while to boot, in fact, it even mentions so :

"This can take a few minutes".

Why does vagrant take a long time to boot?  I would assume its just a thin layer on top of virtual box, which boots quite rapidly in most cases.

Also -- how can i monitor wether the boot is hanging or not?

Some facts :

1) Im using ruby 1.8 in ubuntu 12 as the host, with 64 bit host/vagrant os.

2) TOP sais :

```
                               %cpu    %mem         
   20   0 1820m 686m 650m S     10      18.6   1:03.21 VBoxHeadless
```

Answer (score 1):

These may be related to networking issues preventing the `vagrant` command to connect to the booted virtual machine. You can check the virtual machine is started by running it with the `gui` option on, or have a look to the thumbnail in Virtual Box GUI.

There is an open issue on Github which may match your problem: [issue #455](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/455)

I personally use this in my `Vagrantfile` and the problem just stopped:

```
  # Using hostonly network. You can change this if it doesn't fit your environment
  # (no reason it shouldn't).
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "10.10.10.2"

  # Seems to fix 
  config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--rtcuseutc", "on"]
  config.ssh.max_tries = 10
```

Comment: Can you explain the effect of using `--rtcuseutc`, I had a hard time finding documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

1. modify your vagrantfile to enabled ui [boot](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html)
2. vagrant up with ui boot enabled
3. as soon as possible login as vagrant/vagrant through the ui and do a "top" to verify running process.